# Finding RAL color code for Sea Green (GN6L) paint on a 1969 Saab 96

Tags: paint, old-cars

I am wondering where I could find the RAL color code for the paint color on a 1969 Saab 96 (V4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want part of the car (or the whole car) repainted and thus need the RAL equivalent code?

It might not be a RAL colour, but a paint supplier that's been around for a while might still have the mixing instructions.

That said, if you're looking at getting a partial repaint, the colour code isn't going to help you much - paint fades over the years and you're not going to get a match. The best case for this scenario would be to take the car or a part thereof to a paint shop or paint supplier than can use a [spectrophotometer](http://www.dupontrefinish.eu/portal/en?page=GU-1.3.1_Current_Press_Release&category=PressReleaseCategoryOne&catid=94&catid2=5752) to analyse the paint and mix accordingly.